# How can I concatenate using NCO when one of the dimensions is unlimited?

Tags: unix, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have lots of files with the following header:

```
dimensions:
    grp = 100 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (2184 currently)
    length = 3 ;
    scal = 1 ;
    bands = 2 ;
    midS1AndTime = 52569 ;
    midS2AndTime = 52569 ;
    midT3AndTime = 52569 ;
    t1AndTime = 52569 ;
    t2ndTime = 52569 ;
    t3AndTime = 52569 ;
```

All the files cover the same time period and I want to concatenate by `grp`. Basically, each file has 100 `grp`s each.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

NCO's [ncrcat](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrcat) concatenates files with

```
ncrcat in*.nc out.nc
```

Edit: to address the requirement to concatenate by grp instead of time, the user can convert grp to the record coordinate with `ncpdq -a grp,time`, then use ncrcat as above, then convert back so time is the record coordinate. The [manual](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html) gives examples.

Comment: But this will concatenate by time as time is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using the cat command in CDO for this

```
cdo cat file_*.nc output.nc
```

assuming the wild card * picks up the filenames file_001.nc file_002.nc etc

Hope that works for you.